# How to get 3 or more commits in one commit

Tags: git

I have a developer branch and I didn't push there but I have done more than 7 commits how it is possible from all commits to make one commit and then to push in the developer, because if I push in the developer it will sent more than 10 commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: @Phiter can you show me how --soft works ? by the way thanks for the responding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5201642#5201642

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is through an *interactive rebase*.
You can use `git rebase -i <base_commit>` .
Then you can pick the first commit and squash the rest.

That will merge your commits together in one.

Remember to not modify your already published history

There is a good guide here: [Squash, reword amend](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history)

Comment: Thank you, but in <base_commit> what should i write ?

Comment: So let's say you have commit Q and the master branch points to Q.
You then create develop branch dev pointing to Q as well. 
Now you do your work and end up with seven commits on dev.
In that scenario you run `git rebase -i Q`

Comment: A reference of the commit you whant to rebase to. Just run `git log` command and check hash value for each commit. E.g. the `1eb193b445123ba53ca56bababa54a18b3da9187` value in `commit: 1eb193b445123ba53ca56bababa54a18b3da9187` commit will  be the reference number you're looking for.